# PhpStorm - debug on local, deploy on remote server

Tags: deployment, server, ftp, phpstorm

I'm working on a website using PhpStorm. For a long time I developed it locally, but then I got hosting and a remote ftp server.

I created a new project in PhpStorm with the settings for remote host, and I found that deploying code takes long time (over a minute) before I can see the result, which is quite uncomfortable when debugging.

Is there any possibility to work with code on a local server, and, when I think that the project is ready for deploy, just send it to the server.

I understand, that I can just work in two different projects and just deploy the "ready" version to server via FTP, but maybe there is some more comfortable way?

Comment: So .. what is the problem? That's the basic setup that lots of people use. You code & test locally ... and when ready just upload/sync with remote -- nothing special at all. Have a look at the official guides (in case if you have not seen them yet): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials . I cannot point to any particular one ... as I simply do not see any problem here: you setup local project ... and the just add Deployment entry ... and that's it.

Comment: Thank you for joining the question!

The problem is - why I need two separate projects? If so, I can just use FILEZILLA to send the files to the server. What is the advanatge of using a remote project?

Comment: You do not need 2 projects. I simply do not understand the problem you are having -- such setup (develop locally and deploy to production via (S)FTP when ready) is so common ... that I just do not understand the problem you are having. Yes -- deployment via PhpStorm might be slow (that's the way how it works, checks for file modifications before uploading .. plus the library used itself) ... but you can easily use FileZilla/etc for deployment if so desired.

Comment: So when I need to use option "Web server is on remote host, files are accesible via FTP". For what do I need it?

Comment: That;s asked in the New Project Wizard .. so you can download your files and be ready for "develop here but test or remote server" (e.g. when you do not have your source files located locally already). But you can always do this: 1) create brand new empty project 2) download your files into this folder using FileZilla -- do the basic config and now it's ready for local dev; 3) Setup Deployment entry so you can upload to production when ready.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Maybe, you could write it as answer and I will check it as the best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several answers to this question, and most of them opinion based but i will try and keep it objective.

**Case 1**

A big corporation gives every developer a sandbox, to test their code from, the corp requires every developer to keep their code on the sandbox.
Using mounted drives could be extremely slow. Especially when PhpStorm is indexing.

**Case 2**

An easy way to keep an auto backup of your code it to use the build in (s)ftp(s) upload/deploy.

**Solution**

In both cases you could use the auto deploy feature that saves every changes to the server, that way the deploy doesn't take over a minute, but is usually already there before you know it.

I cannot recommend to use the deployment for Production as it will not pass through your version control, SAT, security setups etc. In that case I would suggest something like rocketeer etc.

**EDIT**:

As for 2 projects, well you can define 2 different deployment servers, and use the default one for your testing, with auto upload or something, and then the other one can be selected from the deployment menu.